# uWSGI-Django spending too much time on poll method

Tags: python, django, sockets, nginx, uwsgi

I am using Nginx-uWSGI combination for my Django project, but the performance is sub-par when I compare it with Nginx-Apache-modwsgi combination. Apparently uwsgi was taking about 3-5 seconds to provide response for requests which should be server in about 300-400ms at most.

When I ran profiling, I realized most of the time is being spend in `response.render` function in uWSGI Handler. Here are the profiling results -

[image: Profiling result]

I am unable to figure out why `method poll` is consuming more than 90% of the time, even when there is just one request on the server.

Here is my uwsgi configuration

```
[uwsgi]
uid = www-data
gid = www-data
listen = 10000
socket-timeout = 60
socket-send-timeout = 60
socket-write-timeout = 60
set-placeholder = username=sysadmin
set-placeholder = project_directory=/home/sysadmin/builds/deploy_dir/qa_shine
set-placeholder = ruby_shims_path=/home/sysadmin/.rbenv/shims
socket = /run/%n.sock
chmod-socket = 666
chdir = %(project_directory)
pidfile = /run/%n.pid
wsgi-file = deploy/uwsgi.py
master = true
processes = 1
threads = 1
harakiri = 160
virtualenv = /home/%(username)/Envs/candidate/
stats = 127.0.0.1:9191
vacuum = true
die-on-term = true
daemonize = /var/log/uwsgi/%n.log
env = LANG=en_US.UTF-8
auto-procname = true
env = PATH=%(ruby_shims_path):$(PATH)
env = RUBYPATH=%(ruby_shims_path)/ruby
rbrequire = rubygems
```

My nginx upstream configuration

```
location / {
    uwsgi_pass django;
    include uwsgi_params;

    proxy_buffering off;
    proxy_buffers 128 128k;
    proxy_buffer_size 128k;
    proxy_temp_path /run/ 1 2;

    uwsgi_read_timeout       60;
    uwsgi_send_timeout       60;
    uwsgi_connect_timeout    60;
    send_timeout             60;
}

# basic conf
events {
    worker_connections  8192;
    use epoll;
    multi_accept on;
}
```

I'm completely lost right now, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why calling twice same library for different processes. And another point `"how to manage your application cache ?"` Like this `import a;import b; #But 'a' include 'b' so you got "(a-b)+2b"`. Multiple delay for every function call.

Comment: Have you tried changing the number of uwsgi processes? Typically, you'd have at least 2, even on a single core machine. You could also specify to have your uwsgi workers to spawn asynchronous threads, but this depends on your environment and what you're hoping to achieve

Comment: Yeah generally I use 10 processes with 2 threads

Comment: But the case remains the same, irrespective of number of processes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I fixed the issue. Apparently the issue was that I'd offline compression disabled, but I was using `sass` files which needed to be transformed into `css` at runtime. Turns out that was causing a lot of IO. When I enabled offline compression, response time fell back to 200ms.